# Lazarus error: Can't take the address of constant expressions

Tags: file, pascal, lazarus

i want to make a simple program to read files in lazarus. But when i try to read a line from txt file compiler give me this error: "Can't take the address of constant expressions"

There is that problematic part -

```
system.Assign(MyFile, label1.caption + '.txt');
  reset(MyFile);
  Readln(MyFile,name);  - this give that error
```

Any suggestion to solve this?

Comment: You need to show us more code. How is your variable `name` defined? It should be a `var name: String;`. If you haven't defined it maybe the name property of your form is taken. Best to define another (more descriptive) variable.

Comment: It's a mater of style but seriously we're in 2014, why the hell don't you use a TStringList/LoadFromFile, TMemoryStream/LoadFromFile or a TFileStream.

Comment: We're in 2014 and files still might not fit into memory :-)

Comment: @MarcovandeVoort: `TStreamReader`would work and doesn't require loading the entire file into memory. :-)

Comment: Ken: equivalent to stream.read(), but not for the proposed loadfrom*

Answer (score 1):

From what you've posted (especially the `label1.caption`), it appears this is from an event handler on a form. In that case, `name` most likely scopes to `Form1.Name`, which is not a variable but a property of the form itself.

Declare a variable of the proper type, and read into it instead. For instance, to read a line of text (example tested in a console application):

```
program Test;

uses 
  SysUtils;

var
  Buffer: array[0..255] of Char;        // Reads up to 256 characters in a line
  LineData: string;
begin
  System.Assign(MyFile, 'C:\Temp\Test.txt');
  Reset(MyFile);
  ReadLn(MyFile, Buffer);
  LineData := Buffer;
  // Do something with LineData
  WriteLn(LineData);
  ReadLn;
end.
```

A much better alternative would be to move away from the old IO functions and into the modern world. For instance, you can use the `Classes.TStreamReader' instead:

```
program Test;

uses
  SysUtils, Classes;

var
  LineData: string;
  Reader: TStreamReader;
begin
  Reader := TStreamReader.Create('C:\Temp\Test.txt');
  try
    LineData := Reader.ReadLine;
    WriteLn(LineData);
    ReadLn;
  finally
    Reader.Free;
  end;
end.
```

Comment: Problem was that variable "name" is reserved - it has value "form1". So when i changed variable "name" to "productname" it works.  Thanks for your time :)

Comment: @MartinBrláž: I said that in my first sentence - it's not 'reserved', it's a property of the form itself.

Comment: To my best knowledge there is no TStreamReader in Lazarus.

Comment: @Marco: OK. You could write one in a pretty short time, or use `TFileStream`, or use `TStringList` and `LoadFromFile`, any of which is better than the old I/O methods.

Answer (score 0):

I tested it and came to the following conclusion:
1.) it's a compiler message - not a runtime-error!
2.) You haven't declared "name" at all. 
So the property 'name' of the form you're in is taken - and this leads to exact that error.

Solution: Declare a string to put the lines into

```
var sTextLine:string; 
begin
    //...
    Readln(Myfile,,sTextLine);
    //...
end;
```